# Fortran error: forrtl severe: file not found, unit 2, mypath\bin\release\fort.2 Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, azure, fortran, windows-server-2012

I have a .NET C# code base that calls Fortran code.  All of this code has been in production working for many months.  We decided to move the application to the Cloud (Azure).  All went well on the migration with the exception of this one piece of code.  This seems to be a setup issue but I'm not sure if it is related to the system overall or the Fortran setup.  I have found advice on this error regarding to how things are coded but not system setups.

The exact error is as follows:

> forrtl: severe (29): file not found, unit 2, file
>   C:\projects...[mypath]\bin\Release\fort.2
>
> Image    PC     Routine     Line    Source libifcoremd.dll 06A618FA
>   Unknown Unknown Unknown (many more lines similar after this one)

I moved from a Windows 2008 R2 physical machine to a Windows 2012 R2 Datacenter machine which may be part of the issue

Comment: Are you running the .NET code on a virtual machine? How did you install your code, using the *Publish* functionality in Visual Studio or did you manually copy files?  Have you tried replacing that "fort.2" file in your bin folder?

Comment: The Fort.2 file isn't in the bin folder.  I think this is part of the Fortran library.  I don't even see fort.2 on either the old or the new system when doing a search for files in Windows.  The overall system is a web application but I also created a stub winForms application to just run this piece and it also fails the same way.  Both the web and winForms Stub application work on the old server.

Comment: The program is doing a READ from unit 2 without opening a specific file on that unit. Intel Fortran will then construct the name fort.2 for that. fort.2 is not "part of the Fortran library" - it's the name synthesized for a data file when the program did not say which file to open.

Comment: Ok, I just did some reading on that and it's slightly more clear.  Any ideas on what would cause the error in one environment where other environments work just fine?

Comment: Search in the code where you read from unit 2. BTW, units under 2 shouldn’t be used for normal files because they can conflict with preopen units.